# How to count number of bytes appearing in the Arduino serial?

Tags: serial, rs485

I need to count the number of bytes appearing in the serial (UART bus) bus, how to count bytes in Arduino with Arduino Serial functions? is this possible?

Application -
RS485 communication with multiple boards **without slave ID**

slave boards will send data to the master board when,

1st 10 bytes = masters send a 10byte message to all slaves

slaves listening to the bus always until it is the turn to send the data

when byte count is 10, slave 1 sends data 5 bytes to master

when byte count is 15 (10+5), slave 2 sends data 5 bytes to master

when byte count is 20 (15+5), slave 3 sends data 5 bytes to master

max count is 25 known value

Comment: `if (Serial.available() > 0) { incoming[byteCount] = Serial.read(); byteCount++; }` where `byteCount` counts the number of bytes received and `incoming[..] ` stores the received bytes, or something like that? Looks like a protocol that's not very fault-tolerant.

Comment: @StarCat I am trying to achieve maximum data throughput. 1st master initiates the bus 10-byte message, all slaves listing to the bus, then slaves sending data when its turn comes. so I can reduce waste time on request response time, I have 20 slaves. maybe each slave send some checksum at last of each slaves data packet where the master can decode once data received

Comment: Counting is easy, the hard part is knowing when to reset the count.  Assume you will sometimes get out of sync.

Comment: @Chris Stratton what did you mean? reset count? i can reset each slave ones the data is sent right? other slaves will wait until there turn

Comment: You need to have a reliable, recoverable way to know when to *start* counting.   Assume the system will occasionally become mis-synchronized for one reason or another, you need to have a design which is self correcting and can get all of the nodes back on board and counting the *next* cycle together.

Answer (score 1):

`Serial.available()` returns the number of bytes available for reading in the buffer.

```
int nBytes=Serial.available();
if (nBytes > x) {
............
............
............
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE.  Just an observation: answers posted here should be written in English.